# Best way to move scale pivot with mirror modifier

Tags: modeling

There are times when I'm box modeling with a mirror modifier where I want to scale a face from the center axis (that I'm mirroring over) NOT the center of the face.

Currently I'm doing this:
Enter Edge Selection Mode and select and edge on the center axis
Shift - S to snap 3d cursor to edge
Use S then X to scale on just the single axis

Is there an easier way to do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this:

1. Switch to edit mode

[image]

2. Switch to edge selection

[image]

3. Select required edge

[image]

4. Shift+S --> cursor to selected

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: @lawrencehagman You are welcome, I've updated my answer and included screenshots. Please accept it if it solved your problem.